# Prime NG does not change my default browser font

Tags: css, angular, fonts, primeng

I can't figure out what I did wrong, or just PrimeNG does not change default font by default? In the css file i can see "--font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;" but in browser its just Times New Roman.

Here is my styles in angular.json
[styles in angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxqsf.png)

Comment: It is changing other things, style or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same issue. For what I found [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=63315), it seems the font is not applied to the body and that you could do the following in your styles.scss:

```
body {
  background-color: var(--surface-a);
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```